# C# Firebird BLOB_SUB_TYPE_0 Image Save

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I have a field like "BLOB_SUB_TYPE_0" in the Firebird database using C#. How can I export pictures?

C# Console.App

[image]

```
using (var conn = new FbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = new FbCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while (reader.Read()) {

                        string fileName = reader["DOSYAADI"].ToString();


                        byte[] blob = (byte[])reader["FILEDATA"];
                        // create a file FileStream to write the data
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\" +fileName, FileMode.Create);
                        fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                        fs.Close();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stack overflow is not a "write my code for me" service.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hello, I added

Comment: Ok, and does this work, or if this doesn't work, what is wrong with it?

Comment: I am saving the picture but the picture is not visible?

Comment: perhaps the data in BLOB is not raw JPEG but some other format, maybe encrypted or compressed

Comment: do u have an option in your program to PUT a jpeg file into the database blob? If yes, then do it and check whether the BLOB has unmodified content of the uploaded file, or somehow transformed one.

Comment: @Arioch'The  Hi, I solved it on the PHP side, first I need to make data by doing Hand then base64_encode. How to make zlib_decode in c #?

Comment: JPEGs in ZLIB ? Wow, someone was creative! Does your screenshot show the beginning of the file or some random middle? For it is certainly not base64, and it is not header (start) of JFIF or ZLib stream either.

Comment: I am encoding base64 to show the image on zipped screen with zlib so compression is just zlib